# simple_form: nested model form elements on one line?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, nested-attributes, simple-form

I am using a nested model form to edit all phone numbers of a client. I think the way simple_form displays it can be improved if I place all phone attributes on one line.

Here is a code I currently have:

```
.main
  .form-inputs
    = f.input :lname, label: t('client.lname')
    = f.input :fname, label: t('client.fname')
    = f.simple_fields_for :phones do |phones_form|
      = phones_form.input :phone, label: 'Phone'
      = phones_form.input :kind, collection: [:home, :work, :cell, :unknown], label: 'Kind'
      = phones_form.input :_destroy, as: :boolean, label: 'Delete?'

  .form-actions
    = f.button :submit, value: t('client.submit'), class: 'btn btn-primary'
```

and it produces the following:
[image]

Is it possible to put nested model's form attributes on one line (like this)?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yah this is a CSS issue. In short you write it in style like so :

```
= phones_form.input :kind, collection: [:home, :work, :cell, :unknown], label: 'Kind', style: 'width: 50px;'
```

Comment: Right. I wonder if it is possible to combine .form-horizontal with .inline fieldset block with twitter-bootstrap.